# How to hide labels in email notifications when fields are empty

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to hide labels in email notifications when fields are empty (when 'include entry details' is checked)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not currently have a way to hide fields that are empty in email notifications. We have had other users request this ability, and have added the idea to our idea board. You are welcome to follow the progress of this [idea](https://trello.com/c/UkcGNSEq) on our idea board.

Also feel free to submit any ideas or features you'd like to see using our [Request a Feature form](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest/).

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. That's great! Would make the email notifications more readable. I'll follow that request on your Trello board.